# Replace data in larger data frame with data from subset

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

This might be basic but I've searched for 25 minutes and haven't been able to find a solution that works for me.

I've subset a data frame (dataSC) for SITE.
I get dataSC_s, which looks like this (but longer):

```
   SURVEY_DATE  SITE   TIME_BLOCK  ACTIVE_FISHING
    1/13/2013    1a-5      9           2
    1/13/2013    1a-5     10           3
    1/13/2013    1a-5     11           3
    1/13/2013    1a-5     12           4
    1/13/2013    1a-5     13           3
    1/13/2013    1a-5     14           4
    1/13/2013    1a-5     15           4
    1/13/2013    1a-5     16           3      
    1/14/2013    1a-5      9           2
    1/14/2013    1a-5     10           3
    1/14/2013    1a-5     11           3
    1/14/2013    1a-5     12           4
    1/14/2013    1a-5     13           3
    1/14/2013    1a-5     14           4
    1/14/2013    1a-5     15           4
    1/14/2013    1a-5     16           3  
    1/15/2013    1a-5      9           2
    1/15/2013    1a-5     10           3
    1/15/2013    1a-5     11           3
    1/15/2013    1a-5     12           4
    1/15/2013    1a-5     13           3
    1/15/2013    1a-5     14           4
    1/15/2013    1a-5     15           4
    1/15/2013    1a-5     16           3
```

I then subset for SURVEY_DATE (and create dataSC_sd) so can do calculations which change ACTIVE_FISHING.
I want to then replace ACTIVE_FISHING in dataSC_s with the new values in dataSC_sd.
I've tried:

```
min.row <- min(as.numeric(row.names(dataSC_sd)))
max.row <- max(as.numeric(row.names(dataSC_sd)))
dataSC_s[min.row:max.row,"ACTIVE_FISHING"] <- dataSC_sd$ACTIVE_FISHING
```

But that doesn't work because the index numbers in dataSC_s are not sequential since dataSC_s is a subset of dataSC.

Does anyone know how I can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dataSC_s[row.names(dataSC_sd),"ACTIVE_FISHING"] <- dataSC_sd$ACTIVE_FISHING
```

so you are indexing the rows that match the rownames of `dataSC_sd`, and since this is a subset of `dataSC_s` it should work. Note that `row.names(dataSC_sd)` is a character vector, so you are indexing by "names" in the same way you are indexing `"ACTIVE_FISHING"`, this works to index over any dimension which has names.